# What is the recommended method to add an RSS icon to an Open Scholar scholar site?

Tags: 6, theming, feeds, distributions

I would like to add a linked RSS icon to the footer of a scholar site using Open Scholar. I know that the URL to an RSS feed will be:
example.com/professorname/feed

However, I'm unsure of how to programmatically get the URL to the scholar site ("example.com/professorname") so I can build the link and insert it into the page.tpl.php for a few scholar sub-themes. Is there a recommended method for this?

Comment: Cross-posted at D.o, but no answers as of this writing: http://drupal.org/node/1414822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an easy to do in the GUI:

1. Go to the Control Panel for the scholar site
2. Click on Site Building
3. Click on Layout
4. Drag the various feed option icons to where you want them to display
5. Have a beer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a footer menu, you could add the RSS feed to it, and then attach a bit of CSS to your theme.  The exact selectors would depend on what is being output, but you could do something like:

```
ul#footer-menu li.menu-1234 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: url(/path/to/rss.png) left center no-repeat;
}
```

You may need to adjust other styles to get the whole icon to appear.

There are bunches of sites with royalty free RSS icons.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't need CSS help, I need help in building the path.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) function, you can pass in the base URL of the site in a custom variable... then in page.tpl.php you can access the base url.

Something like this:

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $base_url;
  global $base_path;
  $variables['site_base_url'] = $base_url . $base_path;
}
?>
```

...and in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php
  // Wherever you want to print out the path, use $feed_path:
  $feed_path = $site_base_url . 'feed';
?>
```

Comment: ...assuming you're using 'professorname' as a site name prefix or something? (in this case, $base_path would be <code>/professorname/</code>).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this did not work. base_path is /, not /professorname

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the way Open Scholar is set up, but I was presuming each professor had his own site, with the base_path as his name. You'll probably need to do something more specialized to get at the professor name. Try using arg(0) to see if you can get the professorname out of that.